# MarkLogic: where should I place the XSLT code when testing xdmp:xslt-invoke in the qconsole

Tags: xslt, xquery, marklogic

I have tried adding it to the database associated with the query that's being run, in the folder of the qconsole itself and in the Modules db, but I still get the error message: "File open error: open '/to-html.xsl': No such file or directory"

This is the code I'm trying to run:
`xdmp:xslt-invoke("to-html.xsl", fn:doc('/docs/before-1.xml'))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the path given to `xdmp:xslt-invoke` will resolve relative to your modules root. But there is a more complex set of rules about the order MarkLogic will use when evaluating paths explained in the documentation:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/import_modules#id_29407

Comment: And the context is determined by the Content Source drop-down in Query Console. That dropdown allows you to run code in Query Console as if it were being run within that specific app server, including using that app server’s modules root to resolve imports and invokes.